# Having same click function and document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load the page with some API calls. I need to perform the same task for a click function as well. My jQuery function is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var result = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://localhost:8080/importantExtensions",
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        if(data[i].empName && data[i].extCode){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].empName+"</td><td>"+data[i].extCode+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt);
                        //("#impExtTableID").html(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }).responseText;
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
```

Can anyone help me to have the same function for a mouse click function as well. I have to perform the same task for a navbar tab. The reason for this requirement is that I want to load the table when the page loads as well as when the nav bar tab is clicked.

Comment: Well, make it a named function, implemented elsewhere and merely call it once in your document ready and also bind it via event listener to your click

Comment: Your code has no errors but still I could not perform click task after the page loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make this a function you can call.  Then call it both in the ready and in the button click.  Assuming your button ID is buttonSample.

```
function callableFunction()
{
var result = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://localhost:8080/importantExtensions",
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        if(data[i].empName && data[i].extCode){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].empName+"</td><td>"+data[i].extCode+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt);
                        //("#impExtTableID").html(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }).responseText;
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    callableFunction();
});

$( "#buttonSample" ).click(function() {
    callableFunction();
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I dont have a button. The click has to be performed for a navbar tab.

Comment: doesnt matter if its a button...as long as you have the ID and put it where buttonSample is...itll work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the contents of the request in a function and use it in the document load & button click event.

```js
//wrapper function for request
function requestFunction() {
  return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://localhost:8080/importantExtensions",
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        if(data[i].empName && data[i].extCode){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].empName+"</td><td>"+data[i].extCode+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt);
                        //("#impExtTableID").html(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }).responseText;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  //call function on load
  requestFunction();
  
  //call function on button click
  $('#button').click(function(){
     requestFunction();
  }); 
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
```

Comment: Why have you used `return false` inside document ready function? At most it should be inside the click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in external function like below:

```js
function init(){
 var result = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://localhost:8080/importantExtensions",
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        if(data[i].empName && data[i].extCode){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].empName+"</td><td>"+data[i].extCode+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#impExtTableID tbody").html(txt);
                        //("#impExtTableID").html(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }).responseText;
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  init();
  $('#btn').click(function(){init()});
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to run the same ajax post but with mouse click?

Use a selector:

```
$(document).on('click','.someClassInYourDom', function() {
  // some code
});
```

Note that you can use this too:

```
$(".someClassInYourDom").click(function() {
  // some code
});
```

But this will work only for selectors which loaded in the first page init.
**The first method is 100% better**, because it will be fired on new content fetched from AJAX too.

If you want to select an ID in the dom you can set `#someIdInTheDom` (note the `#` instead of `.`).
But be aware that if you select an ID, it cant be selected if its been fetched by AJAX request.

For additional info about jQuery, you better read from start to end the great tutorial in W3Schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/

Comment: Do you mean to have two seperate functions for click event and document ready function?

Comment: Depend on your needs. If you need this to be loaded by first page init, then run it on document.ready. If you want to run this again in a latter situation, just use a click selector.

Comment: I want to do both!

Comment: So do both.. put the ajax as a freebie in the document.ready, it will be fired, and put this again, inside the selector.